# Обработка нажатия клавиш двумя окнами независимо от фокуса

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый вечер. Ситуация следующая: имеется два экземпляра окна запущенные параллельно. В классе окна обрабатывается нажатие клавиш:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == keys.Down)
            keys[(int)Game.keyAssociatedWithPlayer[playerIndex][keysType.Down]] = 1;
        ...
    }
```

и аналогично для отпускания клавиш.

Проблема заключается в следующем: нажатия клавиш обрабатываются только тем окном, на котором находится фокус, то есть при нажатии кнопки сигнал об этом доходит только до одного, а нужно чтобы на нажатие кнопки реагировали оба окна: и то которое имеет текущий фокус, и то которое его не имеет.

Существует ли решение данной проблемы в Windows Forms?

Comment: Ну отошлите нажатые клавиши другому окну. А как другое окно собирается обрабатывать? Если на нём есть несколько `EditBox`'ов, в какой из них должны прийти символы?

Comment: @VladD, Данное приложение является игрой с окном на каждого игрока, и нужна возможность одновременно управлять обоими игроками с одной клавиатуры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отделите нажатие клавиш от их обработки.

У вас получится что-то такое:

```
Form2 otherForm;
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ProcessInputKey(e.KeyCode);
    otherForm.InjectKey(e.KeyCode);
}

internal void InjectKey(Keys code)
{
    ProcessInputKey(code);
}

private void ProcessInputKey(Keys code)
{
    if (code == keys.Down)
        keys[(int)Game.keyAssociatedWithPlayer[playerIndex][keysType.Down]] = 1;
    ...
}
```

Вам придётся каждой из форм дать ссылку на другую.